# Concurrent::Promise.all? doesn't work

Tags: ruby, concurrency, promise

I'm trying to make some calculations after I got all promises executed. But `proc` never calls:

```
cbr_promise = Concurrent::Promise.execute { CbrRatesService.call }
bitfinex_promise = Concurrent::Promise.execute { BitfinexService.call }

proc = Proc.new do
  puts 10
end
Concurrent::Promise.all?([cbr_promise, bitfinex_promise]).then { proc }
```

Made with [`concurrent-ruby`](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/) gem.

Should I create a loop that will check this every 100 ms for example?

**Update**

I tried to add a loop and byebug the code (in `sidekiq` worker):

```
while @fl
  Concurrent::Promise.all?([cbr_promise, bitfinex_promise]).then { proc }
end
```

but the `state` of all promises is `pending`. It could be because of byebug, but anyway the `proc` never calls.

Comment: Seems like an issue to open in [concurrent-ruby repo](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/)

Comment: I think I use it wrong way.

Comment: Does not seem like it by [Concurrent::Promise#all? docs](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/frames.html). But it returns boolean and I dont see how this can be chained with [Promise.then](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/frames.html)

Comment: Same, doesn't call `proc`. With while loop too.

Comment: yes, same behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `Concurrent::Promise.all?` returns a `Promise` and you have to execute it
2. you have to pass `proc` as a block argument `&proc`
3. you have to wait for the Promises to finish (e.g. sleep)

This will work:

```
require 'concurrent'

cbr_promise       = Concurrent::Promise.new { p "cbr" }
bitfinex_promise  = Concurrent::Promise.new { p "bitfinex" }

proc = Proc.new do
  puts 10
end

e = Concurrent::Promise.all?(cbr_promise, bitfinex_promise).execute.then(&proc)

sleep 1
```

yields

```
"cbr"
"bitfinex"
10
```

Note how this will not execute `proc` because one of the Promises fails:

```
require 'concurrent'

cbr_promise       = Concurrent::Promise.new { p "cbr" }
bitfinex_promise  = Concurrent::Promise.new { p "bitfinex"; raise 'error' }

proc = Proc.new do
  puts 10
end

e = Concurrent::Promise.all?(cbr_promise, bitfinex_promise).execute.then(&proc)

sleep 1
```

yields

```
"cbr"
"bitfinex"
```

Comment: It is probably worth noting you can call `e.wait` instead of `sleep`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! Was out of internet, so a bit late.